# Differences between developer and production mode CodeIgniter4

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

Today I ran into a interesting problem, was wondering if anyone here know what is happening. I'm developing a Web App with CodeIgniter4, so far everything was working fine, so I decided to spice things up and seed a few thousands registers into some of my tables. Nothing really absurd like a million registers, but enough to stress test the application. It was like 20k registers, so CodeIgniter shouldn't really have a problem, neither should PostgreSQL. But after that, any page related with those tables were taking more than a minute to load.

After a few minutes looking arround trying to find the reason, I stumbled into the "solution". When I set the `.env` to Production, everything runs just fine. But when its set to developer mode, the lag is surreal.

By my understanding, those options should just change the way an error is presented in the Views, beeing developer mode more specific and production mode just some generic "Ops, something went wrong". Is there anything more to it so I can find why my site is lagging so much?

Comment: [Check your DB configuration](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/database.php), see if there are any settings related to `ENVIRONMENT`, eg `'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production')`.  Another option in that DB config which might impact performance is `save_queries`.  Check if that is the problem by manually setting that/those in both environments and compare.  Then get debugging :-)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The problem turned to be the CI4 toolbar. Switched it off and now its working normally in both developer and production mode. Not sure why, but I never really used that anyway, so I won't miss it.

Comment: Glad you solved it, and thanks for sharing the solution, +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you are seeing this 10 years from now with this very specific problem, the solution was turning off the CI4 toolbar in `app/Config/Filters.php` at the section

```
public $globals = [
        'before' => [
            // 'honeypot',
            // 'csrf',
        ],
        'after'  => [
            //'toolbar',
            // 'honeypot',
        ],
    ];
```

Not sure why it was causing the lag, so if you need this toolbar, you might want look a bit further to find out.